# Why can't I reduce(+) on a seq of integers in Scala?

Tags: scala, reduce, infix-operator

I want to get the sum of a `seq` of `Integer`s in Scala.

In my mind I want to fold a plus over the integers like this:

```
val seqOfIntegers:Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val sumOfIntegers = seqOfIntegers.reduce(+)
```

This isn't valid.

Instead I have to do:

```
val sumOfIntegers = seqOfIntegers.reduce(plus)
...
def plus(a:Integer, b:Integer): Integer = { a + b}
```

(I'm sure you could sugar that up - but my point is that the original plus symbol doesn't work as a function, and the errors messages don't make it clear why.)

My question is: **Why can't I reduce(+) on a seq of integers in Scala?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `+` is not a function (that is, an object of type `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`, which is the same as `(Int, Int) => Int`). Instead, it's a *method* on `Int`, which takes another `Int` and returns an `Int`. That is, what you want to pass to `reduce` is
actually `(a: Int, b: Int) => a.+(b)`, which can be sugared into `(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b` and then `_ + _`.

That is,

```
seq.reduce(_ + _)
```

would work as expected.

---

**Making `.reduce(+)` work**

If you want to pass `+` as argument, you have to define a value `+` that extends `(Int, Int) => Int`. For example:

```
object + extends ((Int, Int) => Int) { def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b }
Seq(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(+) 
// res0: Int = 15
```

or, additionally relying on eta-expansion:

```
def +(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
Seq(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(+)
```

So, you *can* invoke `.reduce(+)` on sequences, you just need either a value `+` of the right type `(Int, Int) => Int` (a value, not a method), *or* you need a *binary* method `+` in scope, which takes *two* integers, and can be eta-expanded into `(Int, Int) => Int`.

---

**On error messages**

The error messages seem quite unambiguous. If I don't define `+` myself, and enter

```
Seq(1, 2).reduce(+)
```

into the console, then I get

> error: not found: value +

because there is no value `+` anywhere. I don't know how the error message could be any clearer.